# iPhone: Face recognition feature

Tags: iphone, face-recognition

I have a requirement where I need to recognize the face and should be able to apply some kind of filters(or templates) so that eyes become big/small, able to add moustache, change hair etc. I will have all related graphics ready. I just need to recognize the area of eyes, hair etc and apply those graphic to change the face!

Please let me know if anyone could help to get me into right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: iOS5 SDK has an API for face detection (CIFaceDetector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS5 SDK you can detect faces in a `CIImage` by creating a `CIDetector` of type `CIDetectorTypeFace`.
And then get the list of `CIFaceFeature` objects with the method:

```
- (NSArray *)featuresInImage:(CIImage *)image
```

You can even get the position of the eyes and the mouth.

Comment: Exactly that what I want. Cheers! I will research and use it. Any issues will come back here.